# Tint Color works with native colors but not with the color from pattern image

Tags: ios, swift, tint, bartintcolor

I am theaming the navigation bar back button with the navigation bar tint color it works when I use native colors and it fails when I use custom color from an image.

working code :

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.orange
```

Not working code:

```
let color = UIColor.init(patternImage: someImage)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = color
```

Can someone show some light?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use pattern color for tint color.

Refer the following link:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622467-tintcolor

#### look for this note:

> **Important**
>
> If you attempt to use a pattern color as a tint color, the system
> raises an exception.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a image then please set image in navigationbar as a background image. Like :

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "NavigationBackground"), for: .default)
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Question is about the back button tint color not the bar background itself sir.

Comment: If you have only 1 button (left button) then you can use -
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black

Comment: That is what I am doing, I think u had a trouble understanding my question.